# Create postgresql view in django

Tags: django, postgresql, view, database-view

I want to use postgresql view to store intermediate result of queryset in django.

Is there a good way to create a view in django?

Below is the code of the flow I want!

```py
elements = Element.objects.filter(is_active=True, eventcardad__isnull=False)

# save elements to database view

# reuse the query results by using view
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use raw SQL query to do that read [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/) first.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.